# How to format plot_str() output in R

Tags: r

I'm learning `DataExplorer` package in R. I'm using following R code

```
install.packages('DataExplorer')
library('DataExplorer')
choco=read.csv('flavors_of_cacao.csv',header = T,stringsAsFactors = T)
str(choco)
choco$Cocoa.Percent=as.numeric(gsub('%','',choco$Cocoa.Percent))
choco$Review.Date=as.character(choco$Review.Date)
#checking the dimension of the input dataset and the time of variables.
plot_str(choco)
```

I'm getting following plot.
[image] I would like to make output of `plot_str()` visually more appealing so that I can put it in power point presentation.For example text should be bold with color. Can you suggest me how to do that?

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
plot_str(choco, fontSize = 40)
```

If you look at `?plot_str`, the `...` passes arguments directly to `diagonalNetwork()` and `radialNetwork()` from **networkD3** library. You should be able to customize your charts directly.